# How to use sorting in RxJava and couchbase?

Tags: rx-java, couchbase

I've written below mentioned method to bulk fetch data from couchbase server.

```
bucket.async()
            .query(N1qlQuery.simple(query))
            .doOnNext(res -> res.info().map(N1qlMetrics::elapsedTime).forEach(t -> System.out.println(t)))
            .flatMap(AsyncN1qlQueryResult::rows)
            .flatMap(row -> 
            bucket.async().
            get(row.value().getString("id")))
            .map(JsonDocument::content).
            toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .single();
```

This code is working fine when I pass a query

```
"SELECT meta().id as id FROM bucket"
```

but when I use something like

```
"SELECT meta().id as id FROM bucket order by id ASC"
```

results I am getting are not sorted. However when I run the same query on query console results are as expected. That makes me believe that I am doing something wrong in rxJava. Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order is lost because of the `flatMap()` operator, which apply concurrent streams, but do not maintain order.
When you apply `flatMap()` you are creating and subscribing to a new `Observable` for each `onNext()`, meaning for each row, you're executing in parallel this line:

```
 bucket.async().
        get(row.value().getString("id")))
```

then each of the get operation will finish in a different time, and the fetched content will be emitted non-ordered.

If you want to maintain the order but don't care to lose the parallelism, you should use [concatMap()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concatMap(rx.functions.Func1)) that will maintain only 1 active stream, and will subscribe to each fetch operation in order.

If you do need/want parallelism, you should use [concatMapEager()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concatMapEager(rx.functions.Func1)), that will execute each created Observable in parallel, but will emit the items in order.

Comment: I agree with that, concatMapEager is the way to go I think. We already do this for views & "include docs", see https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/java/view/ViewQueryResponseMapper.java#L220 if you are interested for the details.